# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() not launching process

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime.exec

I have a multi-threaded application that launches an external app to do data conversion in preparation for later parts of the application.

I have an issue that when I set my thread count higher then 6 concurrent threads, the Runtime.getRuntime().exec() fails to launch the external application (I have also tried using ProcessBuilder with the same results).  It does not throw any sort of Exception, and nothing is captured on either the standard output stream or standard error stream.  What's even stranger is upon rebooting the server, I can run at least 8 concurrent threads for a few minutes without the issue, but then the issue will return.

I have read that Linux's implementation uses the fork() command which can cause an unable to allocate memory error, but I am not getting any such error.

I have written another test app to just launch X number of notespad.exe's without issue with X being as large as 100.

The application is running on a Window 2003 standard x64 server in a VMware environment.
JVM version is 1.6.0_11.

I can update the JVM in an attempt to resolve the issue, but would like to leave that as a last effort to prevent needing to test all application with the new JVM version.

Comment: If it doesn't throw any sort of Exception, and nothing comes down sdtout or stderr, then what *does* it do?  Does `Process.waitFor()` return immediately?  What is the result of `Process.exitValue()`?  Perhaps you need to boil this down to a reproducible code example.

Comment: waitFor() returns immediately with a value of 128.  A search tells me that exit code 128 means "There are no child processes to wait for.
ERROR_WAIT_NO_CHILDREN", which would make sense seeing as how the external process is not being launched.

Comment: If the fork command writes outputs to the screen, try writting the output stream to output on your System.out or something and see what happens.

Comment: Both stdout and errout are empty streams.

Comment: I still do not know what the cause of the issue was, but moving my process to a new VM instance appears to have solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to download the dll "framedyn.dll" from http://www.dlldump.com/download-dll-files_new.php/dllfiles/F/framedyn.dll/5.1.2600.2180/download.html and paste on C:\Windows\System32.